# Would this qualify as sarcasm?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Let's suppose a guest brought something inappropriate, like maybe a polo mallet and helmet, to an informal beach party (presumably to show off), and I made a snarky remark to my companion: for example, ***"And me without my jodhpurs."***

Is there a literary term for this kind of humor or device? I'm not sure if it fits the definition of ***sarcasm***. Could it be characterized as ***satire***, or something else?

Comment: Ironic self-deprecation, perhaps?

Comment: _Irony_ could be used (the fact that you're essentially saying 'I should have brought my jodhpurs' while obviously meaning '**NOT**'). With bite, this is _sarcasm_. Anything with bite is _sardonicism_. It's certainly _dry_, if not to the point of _mordancy_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a **humorous/ironic   comment**:

[Humour](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/humour) :

> - [U] the ability to find things funny, the way in which people see that some things are funny, or the quality of being funny:
>   He's got a great sense of humour (= he is very able to see things as funny).

[Irony](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irony):

> - a situation that is strange or funny because things happen in a way that seems to be the opposite of what you expected

(M-W)

- Satire and sarcasm carry stronger connotations which are not probably suitable for the informal context you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that line was **witty**, or the perfect **quip**.

> **[witty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/witty)** *adj*.
>   1. possessing [**wit**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wit) in speech or writing; amusingly clever in perception and expression:
>   *a witty writer*.
>   2. characterized by wit :
>   *a witty remark*.
>
> **[quip](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quip?s=t)** *noun*
>   1.a clever or witty remark or comment.
>   2.a sharp, sarcastic remark; a cutting jest.